# How to replace all the character of string with reference of particular index

Tags: javascript

How to replace all the character of string with reference of particular index.

I have a string like

```
var str = "A1 B1C2"
```

Now I want to check what is the character in 1st index

```
var charAtFirst = str.charAt(1);
```

so I am getting 1.

Now I want to replace all the character which is having value 1. how to do that. Thanks for help.

Comment: [__replace string in JavaScript__](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=replace%20string%20in%20javascript)

Comment: In fact the nembre at the index 1 is the second character and not the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate `RegExp` using the string while creating you need to escape the special meaning characters in the string. After generating the `RegExp` use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
var str = "A1 B1C2";
var charAtFirst = str.charAt(1);

console.log(
  str.replace(new RegExp(charAtFirst.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/, '\\$&'), 'g'), '')
);
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If you want to remove number greater than a particular number then get all numbers and replace by comparing with the number. You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback function.

```js
var str = "A1 B1C2";
var charAtFirst = +str.charAt(1);

console.log(
  str.replace(/\d+/g, function(m) {
    return +m > charAtFirst ? '' : m;
  })
);
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
If you want to increment the character then do it like.

```js
var str = "A1 B1C2";
var charAtFirst = str.charAt(1);

console.log(
  str.replace(new RegExp(charAtFirst.replace(/[|\\{}()[\]^$+*?.]/, '\\$&'), 'g'), (+charAtFirst) + 1)
);
```

Comment: What exactly g do ?

Comment: @David : global flag... to replace all occurenece

Comment: so here I want to replace with the number greater than the number I got at charAtFirst . for that I need to change value of g or something else

Comment: So what I need to use. hope I am clear with question

Comment: @David : ___Now I want to replace all the character which is having value 1___ the above code resolves it

Comment: @David :  for removing number greater than the current value you need to  use some complex code...

Comment: ya, with the value 2. But can't hard cord. will get ther value at char(1) then increment by 1 and replace by the incremented value

Comment: Checked. Thanks for effort But answer should be like "A2 B2C2". 1 is charAt(1) increament value so we get 2 and then replace 1 to 2. Become "A2 B2C2"

Comment: @David :  glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Simple use this

```
var NewStr = str.replace(/1/g, "2");
```